# ¿Cómo colocar dos gráficos de pandas con ejes diferentes en un mismo plot en un mismo plot?

Tags: python

Hola estoy teniendo un problema al momento de ver dos gráficas de archivos .mat cada una tiene diferentes ejes, me sale uno al lado del otro, desearía que me salga los dos en un solo plot.

Mi código es:

```
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

ax.plot(df0_integrated.index, 20*np.log10(df0_integrated.amp),'red',lw=1)

pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

ax.plot(df0_integrated_1.index, 20*np.log10(df0_integrated_1.amp),'black',lw=1)
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `ax` aqui?  Normalmente viene de `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` pero con este `ax` no se puede llamar directamente `ax.plot`

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente basta con seguir añadiendo plots. Si comparten más o menos el mismo rango de valores para los ejes, no hay problemas. (También existe la posibilidad de añadir otro eje al mismo plot.)

Un ejemplo:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

N = 60
index = pd.date_range('2020-01-17 07:30', periods=N, freq='1s')
df0_integrated = pd.DataFrame({'amp':np.random.normal(11000, 5000, N) },  index=index)
df0_integrated_1 = pd.DataFrame({'amp':np.random.normal(14000, 4000, N) },  index=index)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df0_integrated.index, 20*np.log10(df0_integrated.amp),'crimson',lw=1)
plt.plot(df0_integrated_1.index, 20*np.log10(df0_integrated_1.amp),'dodgerblue',lw=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: ejemplo]

Comment: ¿Ha sido útil la respuesta?